# How to resolve an array in a Class when functions depend on each other

Tags: arrays, node.js, async-await, es6-promise

i have two functions.

first one is looping over some folders to get the path, the path is resolved in an array.

Second function get this value and should loop over this array with fs.readdir to check how much images are in those folders.

The function should resolve an object that contains the path and the value how much images are in the folders.

My problem is that i just resolve the first folder properly and instead of a total sum of all the others.

Also i created an callback function that calls an functions that resolves an promise like that:

```
async pResolve(pr) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        res(pr);
    });
}
```

I added this function into the forEach loop like this:

```
let x = pResolve(obj);
res(x);
```

I tried to resolve it in :

```
Promise.all([folderList]).then(arrList => {
console.log(array); 
    });
}
```

The code in the second function looks like:

```
async loopOverArray(){
const getPaths = await this.checkGalleryFolder();

let folderList = new Promise((res, rej) => {

getDir.forEach(val => {
let obj = {};
   fs.readdir(val, (err, data) => {
      obj.path = val;
      obj.img = data.length;
      res(obj);
 });
});
});

}

async checkGalleryFolder() {
const pathArr = [];
return new Promise((res, rej) => {
  fs.readdir(this.p, (err, folders) => {
    folders.forEach((val, i) => {
    if (val.includes("set")) {
    let gPath = this.p + `/${val}`;
    pathArr.push(gPath);
        res(pathArr);

// The function resolves this:
// [ '/sandbox/src/public/set1',
//  '/sandbox/src/public/set2',
//  '/sandbox/src/public/set3' ];

                }
            });
        });
    });
 }
 };
```

As i mentioned i receive an object and it looks like this:

```
[{ path: '/sandbox/src/public/set1', img: 12 }];
```

However the result should look like this:

```
[ { path: '/sandbox/src/public/set1', img: 12 },
 { path: '/sandbox/src/public/set2_f', img: 0 },
 { path: '/sandbox/src/public/set2', img: 12 },
 { path: '/sandbox/src/public/set3', img: 0 },
 { path: '/sandbox/src/public/set1_f', img: 0 } ];
```

How can i resolve this Promise properly?
And why is the checkGalleryFolder() function giving me a proper array and the other not?

Answer (score 0):

ok i changed the loopOverArray() like this and it resolves now an array with all objects!
When someone knows a better way, then please share it :)

```
async loopOverArray() {
    const getDir = await this.checkGalleryFolder();
    let arr = [];

    let folderList = new Promise((res, rej) => {
        getDir.forEach(val => {
            let obj = {};
            fs.readdir(val, (err, data) => {
                obj.path = val;
                obj.img = data.length;
                let x = Promise.resolve(obj);
                x.then(data => {
                    arr.push(data);
                    if (arr.length === getDir.length) {
                        res(arr);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
```